# typing period in VSCode is accidentally bound to something?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prolog

I accidentally bound the period on VSCode on my Mac to something and can't figure out what it's bound to or how to reverse it.

I'm working in prolog, and when I type a period under a fact, it just deletes the period. When I type a period under a rule it replaces the period with that rule name.

I tried out a function in python and it just replaces the period.

I think the video below would explain a little better.

https://streamable.com/4kok5o

I tried enabling Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting, I get this result:

```
[2020-10-02 15:50:05.561] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Period, keyCode: 190, key: .
[2020-10-02 15:50:05.561] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Period, keyCode: 84 ('.')
[2020-10-02 15:50:05.561] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [Period]
[2020-10-02 15:50:05.561] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ No keybinding entries.
```

So I'm thinking it's something else besides key binding.

Comment: Nice video. Didn't understand the details from reading the but the video drives the point home.

Comment: While I use SWI-Prolog with VSC and the vsc-prolog extension. I don't use Pyhton regularly so have not run into this problem. Having said that if and knowing your answer, have you looked at VSC [workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)? I have never used them so setting you up to be the guinea pig if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be the vsc-prolog extension. disabling it fixed it. I couldn't find a way to get it to work with the extension enabled.